# Renaming filenames using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have 2 TextCtrl boxes that works fine for this line:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(self.dirname, f), os.path.join(self.dirname,f.replace(self.BasicRemove.GetValue(),self.BasicReplace.GetValue())))
```

However invoking re.sub on a single box treats this as a string

```
Input - (r'\sAND\s', ' & ', 'Baked Beans And Spam', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

I need to use the last line to work like the fist line.  How can I do this?

```
os.rename(os.path.join(self.dirname, f), os.path.join(self.dirname,f.re.sub(self.AdvanceReplace.GetValue())))
```

Comment: Sample input ? Sample output ? What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: Input (r'\sAND\s', ' & ', 'Baked Beans And Spam', flags=re.IGNORECASE) Output Baked Beans & Spam  I'm entering a regular expression value